# Regex is not matching for shell script: sed 's| *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am facing pretty strange problem, below is shell script with sed command:

```
rec="001  MOVE 'N'    TO abcdefgef"
vname=`sed 's| *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|' <<<$rec`
echo "vname=$vname"
```

output:
vname=001'N'

I am expecting it to be only as 'N' not 001'N'.
Could someone please explain why 001 is coming in output? if regular exp is not matching i should be gettign complete string as ouput. And if 001 is matching how it can miss MOVE word?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rec="001  MOVE 'N'    TO abcdefgef"
$ echo "$rec" | sed 's| *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|'
001'N'
$ echo "$rec" | sed 's|.* *MOVE *\([^ ]*\)|\1|'
'N'    TO abcdefgef

$ echo "$rec" | sed 's|.* *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|'
'N'
$ echo "MOVE 'N'    TO" | sed 's|.* *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|'
'N'
```

Just like you added `.*` to match rest of line after capturing your required string, you need to add `.*` to match string before `MOVE...`

Also, you probably want to match the space after `MOVE` instead of making it optional

```
$ echo "MOVED TO" | sed 's|.* *MOVE *\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|'
D
$ echo "MOVED TO" | sed 's|.* *MOVE \([^ ]*\) .*|\1|'
MOVED TO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do regex matching in bash:

```sh
rec="001  MOVE 'N'    TO abcdefgef"
regex='MOVE *([^ ]+)'
[[ $rec =~ $regex ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="MOVE '\''N'\''" [1]="'\''N'\''")'
```

["BASH_REMATCH" is an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) that, if the match succeeded, will be populated with the matched text (in array index 0) and the captured parts of the regex (in subsequent indices)